# The page isn’t redirecting properly

Tags: 8, redirection

I have been trying to intercept a page request from `/node/nid` which is of type `the_content_type` and then appending some facet query parameters to it which is something like this

`?f[0]=city%3A160&f[1]=country%3A48`.

The purpose is to preselect the facet options from that page.

Here is the subscriber class I have written so far

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom_module\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse;

class RedirectWithFilterSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    // This announces which events you want to subscribe to.
    // We only need the request event for this example.  Pass
    // this an array of method names
    return([
      KernelEvents::REQUEST => [
        ['redirectWithFilter'],
      ]
    ]);
  }

  /**
   * Redirect requests for my_content_type node detail pages to node/123.
   *
   * @param GetResponseEvent $event
   * @return void
   */
  public function redirectWithFilter(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    // This is necessary because this also gets called on
    // node sub-tabs such as "edit", "revisions", etc.  This
    // prevents those pages from redirected.
    if ($request->attributes->get('_route') !== 'entity.node.canonical') {
      return;
    }

    // Only redirect a certain content type.
    if ($request->attributes->get('node')->getType() !== 'the_content_type') {
      return;
    }

    $node = $request->attributes->get('node');
    $node_id = $node->id();
    $node_url = $node->url();
    $country = $node->field_country->getValue();
    $city = $node->field_city->getValue();
    $country_target_id = $country[0]['target_id'];
    $city_target_id = $city[0]['target_id'];

    if (empty($country) && empty($city)) {
      return;
    }

    // This is where you set the destination.
    $option = [
      "query" => [
        "f" => [
          "city:$city_target_id",
          "country:$country_target_id"
        ]
      ],
    ];

    $redirect_url = Url::fromUri("entity:node/$node_id", $option);
    $response = new RedirectResponse($redirect_url->toString(), 301);
    $event->setResponse($response);
  }
}
```

The resulting url looks fine though

`http://project.dev/some-custom-page?f%5B0%5D=city%3A160&f%5B1%5D=country%3A48`

But the problem is, the page always shows

`The page isn’t redirecting properly`

on my browser. I've been figuring this out for almost 3 days now and I can't seem to find a way through it. I've been wanting someone to have a fresh look into it. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Is there somebody can lend me a help please? Or maybe, a different way other than this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a redirect loop. You have to check whether the query string is already present and then stop redirecting again:

```
  public function redirectWithFilter(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $request = $event->getRequest();
    if ($request->query->has('city')) {
      return;
    }
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for feedback 4k4. It really helps me to figure out the problem and allow me to fix the issue. I have modified a bit your answer to suit my needs.

Comment: This is how I did it.

$query = $request->query->all();

    if ($query['f'][0] == "city:$city_target_id") {
      return;
    }

    if ($query['f'][0] == "country:$country_target_id") {
      return;
    }